# How to find tweets of all users from a particular location

Tags: twitter

I am trying to specify the location in the search bar of Twitter.
Here is my query
`lang:en since:2011-05-15 until:2020-01-13 -filter:links -filter:replies`
I know there are two parameters like `near` and `within` to search based on location. But I am unable to figure, how to use them. I think they are deprecated. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's advance search `near:` operator works only with names of cities. It is a bit tricky to use it when the city name has 2 or more words and even trickier to use when the desired city is in a country where the language (and original city name) is in a non-latin language.

The more acuarte way to limit a Twitter search to a particular location or place is to use the `geocode:` operator with `latitude`,`longitude` and `radius(km/mi)` parameters.

For example, your above search query, [for tweet originating from the city of New York](https://twitter.com/search?q=lang%3Aen%20since%3A2011-05-15%20until%3A2020-01-13%20-filter%3Alinks%20-filter%3Areplies%20geocode%3A40.6887908%2C-73.9273234%2C30km&src=typed_query&f=live), you can use the following:

```
lang:en since:2011-05-15 until:2020-01-13 -filter:links -filter:replies geocode:40.6887908,-73.9273234,30km
```

The easiest way to get `latitude` and `longitude` of places is to user [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps). Simply search or pinpoint the desired location. The `latitude` and `longitude` are the first 2 parameters after the `@` sign in the URL line in the browser, separated with a coma `,`:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+York,+NY,+USA/@40.6976637,-74.119764,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62!8m2!3d40.7127753!4d-74.0059728
```